# SQLite Format Seconds

Tags: sql, sqlite

Suppose there is a value 20 which is in seconds in the table.
I want to return 20 in the format: 00:00:20

Also if there is 120 seconds it should return in the format: 00:02:00

I tried using datetime, time, strftime functions, but still did not get it right.

Can anyone give me a query to perform this in SQLite3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the [supported date/time formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime) is a number of seconds, so you just have to tell the [date/time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to interpret the number of seconds in that format by using the `unixepoch` modifier:

```
> SELECT time(120, 'unixepoch');
00:02:00
```

Comment: Heyy Thanks a lot for the help. Yeah I was playing around using unixepoch but with the wrong function.